# How many ways can n different objects be split up into r groups, where each group is of size q, and where $n \geq r q$

Tags: combinatorics

I'm wondering how many ways n different objects can be split up into r groups, where each group is of size q, and where n >= r * q. I know that, when n = r * q, there is a straightforward solution (the formula, as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475052/proving-that-the-number-of-ways-mn-different-objects-can-be-divided-into-m-g), is (n!) / (((q!) ^ r) * (r!)). When n > r * q, though, does the formula change? (The extra n - (r * q) objects are discarded and not assigned to any groups.)

I believe (from simulations) that the formula is (n!) / (((q!) ^ r) * (r!) * ((n - (q * r))!)) (in other words, there is an additional factor of ((n - (q * r))!) in the denominator, and since 0! = 1, this formula still holds true when n = r * q), but I'd like to confirm if this formula is correct.

Thanks!

Comment: There are $\binom{n}{rq} = \frac{n!}{(rq)!(n-rq)!}$ ways to pick $rq$ objects, then for each way, follow the original question.

Comment: If each of $r$ groups has exactly $q$ elements, then you can't have $n>rq,$ unless you are using "split up," already an undefined term, very imprecisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many problems like this can be solved with a method of choosing twice. In this case, first you can choose which $q\cdot r$ objects you want to use and then you choose their exact partition. For the first choice, there are $\binom{n}{qr}$ possibilities and you already described the number of the second choices. The result is the product of these, as for each first choice, you have the same number of possible second choices. Different pairs of choices lead to different "splits" and every "split" is counted once, so the product is really the answer.

PS: Please use MathJax for mathematical formulas for better readability.